# Get the count of nested *ngFor loop filtered array from outside the loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

Currently I have used @ViewChildren decorator. But it seems it's not helping.

```
<div class="" *ngFor="let trip of flight.main.flightData.rows; let i = index; trackById" [attr.data-index]="i" >
        ........
        <div class="clearfix dateatime more-option" *ngFor="let option of trip.rows | subDepArrTime: i:selectedDepTime[i]:selectedArrTime[i]; let j=index;" [class.hidden]="!hideMe[x][i] && j > 0" #filtered[i]>
          ......
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix more">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" *ngIf="filteredItems[i]?.length - 1 !== 0" (click)="hideMe[x][i]=!hideMe[x][i]"><span>+ {{filteredItems[i]?.length - 1}} more timing option(s)</span></div>
        </div>


      </div>
```

Comment: why not just use the `.length` property of array

Comment: @RahulSingh I want to get the length of  this **fiitered** array `*ngFor="let option of trip.rows | subDepArrTime: i:selectedDepTime[i]:selectedArrTime[i]; let j=index;"` **from the outside** of that loop. It's inside another loop so it's dynamic as well.

Comment: did you resolve the problem

Comment: @beginerdeveloper Had to place it inside the loop and got the filtered array like `*ngFor="let option of trip.rows | subDepArrTime: i:selectedDepTime[i]:selectedArrTime[i] as trips; let j=index;"`